# C# custom data type

Tags: c#, types, ref, modbus

I'm struggling to understand something in order to use a specific method in a library that was sent to me in order to control a device on Modbus RTU.

My question has nothing to do with the actual Modbus though. I'm pretty sure I'm just missing some basic info on C#.NET as I don't have too much experience. I don't really know what to look for either.

The library is from Orientalmotor and called omrlib. It includes some specific functions for their motors. Some of them I can use without any issue, for example I can get the speed of a stepper motor like this:

```
modbus.ReadParameter(1, 0x480, out operatingSpeed);
```

In this particular example I'm reading from driverID 1 and the speed happens to be located in register 0x480.

The problem I'm having arrises when I'm expecting some (custom) data to return, for example using the method *SendDiagnosis* would return 2 bytes that I need to read. The syntax for this is

```
modbus.SendDiagnosis(response, slvadd, data)
```

slvadd is a byte that corresponds with the ID of the driver. *data* is a ushort where I would have to send 0x1234, but I can't figure out what to use for *response*. Intellisense lists the type as **ref Omrlib.Communication.ModbusInfo.SendReceiveData**

[image: Screenshot]

I suppose I have to declare a variable with this type but I can't for the life of me figure out how I have to do that, and how I can read the reply that will be stored in this response (the driver should reply with the same message 0x1234).

Could anyone offer some insight please?

Thanks!
Jens

Comment: I don't know this library, but you have to create an object of this type `var resp = new SendReceiveData();` and then pass it by reference to the method `modbus.SendDiagnosis(ref resp, slvadd, data);`

Comment: After you make the call `resp` will have the "response", meaning the callee will set its properties and fields. At least, by convention, that's what it should do. Do not, however, take this to mean that you should use `ref` parameters yourself. There are very limited use cases for that.

Comment: ok thanks! The code now compiles correctly. I'm not sure how I can get the bytes that should be now be stored in `resp`. I have tried to to show them using `MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(resp);`but that displays quite literally "Omrlib.Communication.ModbusInfo.SendReceiveData", which is probably an effect of the .ToString function.

Comment: Put a break point after you receive the response and use the debbuger to see its properties and see which one has the data you need

Comment: Or let intellisense do the job)

Comment: Ok, I think I'm closing in on the problem. In debugger mode I have found the bytes by hovering over resp. It will then give me "Response - Non-Public members - @data" and finally a table from 0 to 255 where I see my bytes in position [2] and [3]. Now to access them..